# Create db from sql script in VS 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

I have worked on Visual studio 2008 before, but do not have a lot of experience in working with databases. I have a Sql Script file which contains the complete information about the datanase that i am supposed to replicate and use in my project(which is a web site). Could someone guide me as to how am i supposed to use the Sql script file to create the database...?
The language i am using is C#.
Thanks a lot...

Comment: do you know what kind of database the script is for? (for example SQL Server, Oracle, mysql)

Comment: I found it out, its SQL server...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just run the sql script directly on the SQL engine.

From the command prompt: `sqlcmd -i C:\myScript.sql`

Or open it in Server Management Studio, and hit execute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx